# Name / title of a story about a sentient submarine battleship?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think I read this (probably in an anthology) around 1972. As I remember it -- this sentient submarine battleship is left over from a war and awakens when challenged. Is this Van Vogt?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I just found this by scanning an anthology of Van Vogt. The short story is very short and called ITSELF.

http://www.icshi.net/sevagram/biblio/itself.php

Answer (score 2):

May be T. J. Bass' [*The Godwhale*?](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/057512993X)

from the Amazon link:

> Rorqual Maru was a cyborg—part organic whale, part mechanized ship—and
>   part god. She was a harvester: a vast plankton rake, now without a
>   crop, abandoned by earth society when the seas died. So she selected
>   an island for her grave, hoping to keep her carcass visible for
>   salvage. Although her long ear heard nothing, she believed that man
>   still lived in his hive. If he should ever return to the sea, she
>   wanted to serve. She longed for the thrill of a human's bare feet
>   touching the skin of her deck. She missed the hearty hails, the sweat,
>   and the laughter. She needed mankind. But all humans were long gone—or
>   were they?

Comment: No, I thought of Bass The Godwhale. It's not that. Shorter and more of a "war" novel. It might be by Van Vogt but...